# D3.js V5 tree in svg layout

Tags: d3.js, svg

*I create three svg paint board in body element, and i want create a tree layout in first svg. But the tree layout always show at last one. I can't find some error in my codes. 3Q*

result in html:
[html result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJPyP.png)

my d3.js(v5) code shown below:

```
var svg = body.append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
svg.append('rect')
  .attr('width', '100%')
  .attr('height', '100%')
  .attr('fill', 'rgb(255, 100, 100)')

d3.json('map_tree.json').then(function(datas){

  var root = d3.hierarchy(datas)
  var tree = d3.tree()
    .size([height, width-120])
    .separation(function separation(a, b){
      return a.parent == b.parent ? 1:2
    })
  tree(root)

  svg.append('g')
    .selectAll('circle')
    .data(root.descendants())
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 4)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(50, 0)')
    .attr('fill', 'white')
    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1)
    .attr('cx', function(d, i){
      return d.y
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d, i){
      return d.x
    })
    .attr('cx', function(d, i){
      return d.y
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d, i){
      return d.x
})

var svg = body.append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
svg.append('rect')
  .attr('width', '100%')
  .attr('height', '100%')
  .attr('fill', 'rgb(100, 255, 100)')

var svg = body.append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
svg.append('rect')
  .attr('width', '100%')
  .attr('height', '100%')
  .attr('fill', 'rgb(100, 100, 255)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I hava found the reason. I created more than one d3.select('doby').append('svg') named svg, and the problem has gone when i named others with svg1、svg2